# Minimize repeated summation of numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I recently came across this [post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimize-the-sum-calculated-by-repeatedly-removing-any-two-elements-and-inserting-their-sum-to-the-array/)

The solution given is elegant and it got me thinking. What if we are not allowed to sort the list and can only take 2 adjacent elements i.e at indcies $x,x+1$ (this also includes first and last numbers, it is like a round circle of numbers)and sum them instead of any 2 elements at random indices. What could the optimal algorithm be?

One naive way would be to always take the minimum 2 elements and perform exactly what is given in the link. But this doesn't seem efficient to me.

Can someone prove/provide a better way to approach this?

**Update**:
After a comment, i would like to add this for further clarification about how the sum of numbers is being done

We are interested in an accumulated sum. Consider an a, b, c list. Select a, b. The list becomes a+b, c and the acc sum becomes a+b. On the next step the list reduces to a+b+c, and the acc sum becomes (a+b) + ((a+b) + c) = 2a + 2b + c. Working from another end we'd achieve a + 2b + 2c.

Now , from above, we would want to minimize the answer.

Comment: Where is the sum of the two elements inserted in the list?

Comment: If we sum up numbers at x & x+1, thier sum is put at their position and both the numbers that are used to get the sum are deleted  .Essentially, if your list is say 1 2 3 4 , and we sum up 1 and 2 the new list becomes 3 3 4

Comment: I don't understand. Addition is commutative. Why does it matter what order you sum the elements? The final sum will always be the same, won't it? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe The problem statement is indeed confusing. We are interested in an accumulated sum. Consider an `a, b, c` list. Select `a, b`. The list becomes `a+b, c` _and the acc sum_ becomes `a+b`. On the next step the list reduces to `a+b+c`, and the acc sum becomes `(a+b) + ((a+b) +  c) = 2a + 2b + c`. Working from another end we'd achieve `a + 2b + 2c`.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you for clarifying.